CheckBox pywinauto how to click inside ListViewWrapper
I have a table object with one row in it. I want to click on the CheckBox inside this line, but all I could do was click on the line itself, but not on the CheckBox.
Code:
app = Application().connect(title="Название окна программы")
window = app['Название окна программы']

table = window.child_window(control_type="Table", title="Название таблицы")

items = table.items()

for item in items:
    if 'CheckBox' in item.friendly_class_name():
        item.click_input()
        break

How do I click on the CheckBox to put a check mark there?
pywinauto version == 0.6.8

Add param where="check" here: item.click_input(where="check")

Other examples are here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/unittests/test_common_controls.py#L337

@VasilyRyabov TypeError: BaseWrapper.click_input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'where'

Try Application(backend="uia"), but script could be re-written, because the UI elements hierarchy may look a bit different (more rich). By the way, control_type is more typically used for backend="uia", default backend "win32" typically needs class_name keyword.

@VasilyRyabov I use Application(backend="uia") specifically. I can't figure out exactly what the problem is. Maybe I have an incorrect version of pywinauto installed (although I doubt it), maybe there is some way to check this?

@VasilyRyabov I decided to roll back to another version == 0.6.4. I lost the items() method for an object with control_type == Table, but I was able to get around this point by counting the CheckBox in the row. The click_input() method, as well as the usual click(), started returning the error got an unexpected keyword argument 'where'. I can't figure out what the problem is, it's quite difficult to figure out the methods.

Well, I think it is faster to chat. Please find me in Telegram: @vasily_v_ryabov
